# Jasper report decimal format with zero value is giving null

Tags: java, jasper-reports

We are using jasper report.

And for one of field in report we have set formula, like if value of rate1 field is null then display **"-"** in report otherwise format `rate1` value such as **##0.0000**.

> $F{rate1}?new DecimalFormat("##0.0000").format(new
>   BigDecimal(""+$F{rate1})):"-"

But if value of `rate1` is 0 then also it is displaying **"-"** instead of **0.0000**
What can be issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change it to following.

```
$F{rate1} != null ? new DecimalFormat("##0.0000").format(new BigDecimal(""+$F{rate1})):"-"
```

To explain, I have not checked in JasperReports and dont have a setup to test right away.
**But In C, zero is considered false, while a non zero value is considered true.**

Somewhere while the reports are being parsed and executed this *might* be happening, this might be the scenario happening. You better confirm with the community about this.

Comment: Java does not have automatic conversion from int (or String) to boolean, so in plain java syntax like presented in the question is illegal. However, since it apparently worked somehow I am also inclined to belive that this change will make it better.

Comment: I agree. But may be jasper **might be** doing something internally before directly evaluating the expression, that's why I asked him to check with community. Because my last experience was with 4.5.1 and they're 5.6.0 so things might have changed. 
And anyway the expression in the given format is wrong. :)

Comment: It might be that the asker is writing his expressions in Groovy rather than Java. This has been possible since JasperReports 0.6.6, and would explain the automatic type conversion.